Python if/else/elif
I'm trying to learn python and I have an issue with an if statement. I'm getting an input in string form that asks you to guess a word/character in the output sentence. I'm trying to get two different outputs for it. One output would be "Character x does/doesn't appear in the output sentence" and the other is "Word x does/doesn't appear in the output sentence". I set up a variable that checks the length of the input and decides if it's a character or a word. I can get the output to differentiate between characters and words but i cant get it to say "... doesn't appear in the output sentence". Code is below, please help me, I'm trying to understand how python works.
name = input("What's your name?: ")
name_charcount = len(name)
birth_year = input("Birth year: ")
age_years = 2024 - int(birth_year)
age_months = 12 * int(age_years)
age_days = 365.3 * int(age_years)
weight_kg = input("Weight in kg: ")
weight_lbs = float(weight_kg) * 2.20462262
welcome_message = "Welcome back " + name + ", you are " + str(age_years) + " years old (approximately " + str(age_months) + " months or " + str(age_days) + " days) and weigh " + str(weight_lbs) + " lbs"
find_word = input("Guess a word or a character in the output sentence: ")
find_character_length = len(find_word) <=1
find_word_length = len(find_word) >=2
find_years = find_word in welcome_message

print(welcome_message)

if find_character_length:
    print("Character " + find_word + (str(find_years).replace('True',' does appear in the output sentence')))
elif find_word_length:
    print("Word " + find_word + (str(find_years).replace('True', ' does appear in the output sentence')))
else:
    print("Character/Word " + find_word + (str(find_years).replace('False','does not appear in the output sentence')))


Thought experiment: Under what circumstance will both find_character_length and find_word_length be falsy? Your test isn't checking whether the substring appears in the string at all, you're checking if it's a character or a word.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is a Q&A site, so what's the question exactly? I think the best thing you could do to help yourself learn would be to take a step back and organize the problem: what input to find_word should result in what output? Make a [mre]. For more tips, see What is the proper way to approach Stack Overflow as someone totally new to programming? Then if you still need help, check out [ask] for tips like how to write a good title.

FWIW, str(find_years).replace('True', ...) is a ridiculous approach (no offense, we've all been beginners at some point). Instead, you probably want a conditional expression like: 'does' if find_years else 'does not'

Mistakes:

you don't have to use else, it is never going to occur because, the input will be either word/character according to your verification[x<=1,x>=2 union of both these condition is universal set,so there is no else required]
Both True and False are output of same str(find_years) so you have to replace true,false both one by one in same line (you can do it simultaneously with regex, but it is not going to save you much costs)

Edit 1:
as mulan pointed out, str(boolean).replace("True",something) and etc. is worser as boolean can directly be used to do things with if, converting it to string and replacing it costs higher, so you can use the below code:
.
.
.
find_word = input("Guess a word or a character in the output sentence: ")
find_character_length = len(find_word) <=1
find_word_length = len(find_word) >=2
find_years = find_word in welcome_message

print(welcome_message)

#Changes
thing = "Character " if find_character_length else "Word "
print(thing + find_word + (' does appear in the output sentence' if find_years else ' doesn\'t appear in the output sentence'))

Look at changed part of code
I used oneliner for elegance

str(p).replace('True', x).replace('False', y) is a bad way to write x if p else y, not to mention it causes unexpected results if x contains the word "False".

i wanted to show how to make it work in OP's style so there is not a lot of changes, didnt think of optimisation,yet i will do it now

the issue i was trying to solve was not only finding out if it's a word or a character but also if it does or doesnt appear in the output

well that is solved right? whats the problem @segalsxo

yea i didnt notice the edit, thank you so much

actual oneliner print("Character" if find_character_length else "Word", find_word, "does" if find_years else "doesn't", "appear in the output sentence")
